# XPATH Get Multiple Values within same Element in an RSS Feed

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing, foreach, rss

I have an rss feed that is formatted something like this:

```
<item>
     <posturl>mysite.com/abc.html</posturl>
     <imagepath>123.jpg</imagepath>
</item>
<item>
     <posturl>mysite.com/def.html</posturl>
     <imagepath>456.jpg</imagepath>        
</item>
<item>
     <posturl>mysite.com/ghi.html</posturl>
     <imagepath>789.jpg</imagepath>    
</item>
```

I have a script where I want to extract both the values above. I can extract one of the values and build html code using code like:

```
<?php
     $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://myrssfeed.com');
     $imgs = $xml->xpath('//imagepath');
            echo '<ul>';
         foreach($imgs as $output1) {
            echo '<li><img src="' . $output1 . '" ></li>';
            }

            echo '</ul>';
 ?>
```

This works like a charm thanks to all the help from people here. But I need to expand that **second** echo line to read something like:

```
echo  '<li><a href="' . $output2 . '"><img src="' . $output1 . '" ></a></li>';
```

I need help on how to extract $output2 = posturl within the same item as $output1.

Basically I need to display the images as links... both imagepath and posturl are elements within item.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the `<item>` elements instead of `<posturl>` and `<imagepath>`. Like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://myrssfeed.com');

echo '<ul>';

foreach($xml->xpath('//item') as $item) { 
    printf('<li><a href="%s"><img src="%s" /></a></li>', 
        $item->posturl, $item->imagepath); 
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Awesome... works perfectly. I tried for a whole day straight.... I really appreciate you help!!!

Comment: Sorry one more question... I have a third item that (thanks to you) I figured out how to add to the printf... but what if I wanted to eliminate all the periods in that result and replace them with spaces... Thank you again.

Comment: Use `$result = str_replace('.', ' ',$result);` to replace the periods.